# Selecting a data attribute name via variable

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out what the correct syntax is:

```
<select>
    <option data-option1="test"></option>
</select>
```

jquery (where index is a running through loop):

```
$('fieldset').each(function(index, element){
   var name = 'option'+index;
   var res = $('select').find(':selected').data(name);

   console.log(res);
});
```

These work:

```
var name = 'option1';
var name = 'option'+1;
```

This doesnt (index is definitely registering correctly as I'm using it to select other elements):

```
var name = 'option'+index;
```

I've tried changing toString() etc. in case it's that but can't figure it out. It works if I just use the name e.g. data('option1') but not when its a variable

Comment: The `select` element does not have a `data-option1` attribute.

Comment: Yep apologies - I am looking for the selected options data attr - have updated

Comment: So you have multiple option elements that all have that data-attribute?

Comment: yep correct I'm just getting the :selected ones value - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("option").data(name);` to get the data-attribute value. Also the attribute is on option and not on select so use the correct selector.

```js
var index = 1;
var name = "option"+index;
var res = $("select option").eq(index-1).data(name);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option data-option1="test"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will iterate over all option elements unnecessarily. Why not outright select the one option element you care about?

Comment: How do you know the index has any connection to the select element? As far as I can see it's merely used to construct the name of the data property to be accessed.

Comment: @connexo OP has mentioned `where index is a running through loop`.

Comment: This also doesn't work. It works if I add the index as a string like in the example but my index is coming from an each() loop. It seems that the index is the issue

Comment: @bigLdot and now what is fieldset? Can you post html too?

Comment: I have but it doesnt matter. Its getting stuck on the index as it works when its 'option'+1

Answer (score 0):

The `select` element does not have a `data-option1` attribute.

You need to not only ask the correct data-attribute, but also ask it from the element that actually **has** that attribute:

```js
let index = 1
let name = 'option' + index

console.log($(`select option[data-${name}]`).data(name));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option data-option1="test"></option>
</select>
```